# Strange Nodes in imported .obj file from Alias .wire export

Tags: import

I exported an .obj file from Alias, then import it to Blender. It was able to import, but all I see is broken surfaces/edges and lots of CVs/points.

I've also tried with .fbx format, the mesh will not be shown at all in Blender.

Anyone can help? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Blender requires a specific fbx version on import. Which Alias version are you using, and which version of Blender? Did you tessellate the data in Alias before export?

Comment: Blender version 2.79, Alias 2017, FBK 2016. I wasn't able to tessellate data during .obj export.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When transferring data from application A to application B, the challenge is that there is always two potential sources of the problem. In your case, I suspect it to be an incomplete Alias export. You've stated in the comments that you were not able to tessellate the data during .obj export. Just in case, you have been using settings similar to the ones in the screenshot below?

[image]

Note that Tessellate is checked (the tolerance depends on your model), and that the output units are set to Meters. Importing such a file to **Blender 2.79b** worked fine for me in a quick test.

If you still get a faulty export, it's worth converting the data yourself to Meshes before exporting. The NurbsToMesh tool from the Palette is your friend:

[image]

If you check `use existing tessellation` you don't need to enter values yourself. The existing viewport shading tessellation is used instead. Pick the resulting Meshes and export them to OBJ as proposed above.

The preferred way is to use the .fbx Interface, but there were API changes in Alias from 2017 to 2018, resulting in different options available. The screenshot here is from Alias 2018. Note the File Version setting, which is important for Blender to be able to read the .fbx:

[image]